# Discord.js v13 bot displays undefined instead of emoji

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want my bot to display emoji from another server, but instead of emoji, I get undefined. The emoji ID is correct. Here is my code:

```
const emoji = client.emojis.cache.get("<:money:914429973593468938>")
message.reply(`${emoji}`)
```

Comment: Collections map by ID. `.get("914429973593468938")`. You might need to look into `resolve()` instead: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseGuildEmojiManager?scrollTo=resolve

Comment: You are trying to access a cached emojis and the emoji you are looking for might not be in the bot's cache so that's why you are getting undefined.

Comment: @iiRealistic_Dev thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use `message.reply("<:money:914429973593468938>")` instead. work just fine for me.
Yeah I know your question already answered in comment